# Make figure stick out past the margin

Tags: margins, wrapfigure

I want to use wrapfig to insert a figure which sticks out into the margin.  This does not work, it causes the figure to appear at the end of the text:

```
{\addtolength\textwidth{1in}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{funcimmet1.pdf}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Graph of $2{{\sin }^{2}}x-1$}
\end{wrapfigure}
}
```

This makes the picture bigger but it doesn't stick out, it eats up more space to the left:

```
\addtolength\textwidth{1in}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{funcimmet1.pdf}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Graph of $2{{\sin }^{2}}x-1$}
\end{wrapfigure}
\addtolength\textwidth{-1in}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You probably don't want to use `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`. That adds extra vertical spacing. Inside `figure`s and `table`s, you want `\centering`.

Answer (score 5):

The wrapfigure has an optional parameter for this. Use the full definition

```
[number of narrow lines] {placement} [overhang] {width of figure}

Placement is one of   r, l, i, o, R, L, I, O,  for right, left,

The figure sticks into the margin by `overhang', if given.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\makebox` to put the picture into a smaller box like in [this blog post](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/centering-figure-table/), such as

```
\makebox[smaller width]{\includegraphics[bigger width]{funcimmet1}}
```

Comment: That's going to center the graphic in the smaller box which would have the effect of extending it into the text. `\hbox to smaller width{\includegraphics[bigger width]{funcimmet1}\hss}` or `\makebox[smaller width][l]{\includegraphics[bigger width]{funcimmet1}}` would cause the box to extend to the right.

Comment: Correct, I just did not mention the optional alignment argument.